# Receive JSON data post to ASP page in Json format

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I am Trying to Post Json data from html page to ASP page  and receive it in a function.
like this:

```
        address1 = [["123  Main St", "", "MESA", "AZ", ""],
        ["5088 n  desert ln", "", "PRESCOTT VALLEY", "AZ", "86314"]];
        address1 = JSON.stringify(address1);


        $.ajax({

            url: "Default2.aspx/GetPostData",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{"address1":"' + address1 + '"}',
            traditional : true,
            success: function (data2) {
                alert("success::" + data2.d);

            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("ERROR:::" + response.d);
            }
        });
```

and receive it in following function in asp page

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetPostData(String address1)
{
          ------
}
```

But data is not receiving in json format 
it is received as a text
As shown

123  Main St,,MESA,AZ,,5088 n  desert ln,,PRESCOTT VALLEY,AZ,86314

i want to receive it as json only ..

Please suggest what wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two issues here:

1- In your Ajax call the json is not valid. change it to. also make your address elements more standard.

var address1 = [{ "Street1": "123  Main St", "Street2": "", "City": "MESA", "State": "AZ", "Zip": "" },
                { "Street1": "5088 n  desert ln", "Street2": "", "City": "PRESCOTT VALLEY", "State": "AZ", "Zip": "86314" }];

$.ajax({

```
            url: "http://localhost:63850/Default.aspx/GetPostData",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: '{"address1":' + address1 + '}',

            //'{"address1":"' + address1 + '"}',
            traditional: true,
            success: function (data2) {
                alert("success::" + data2.d);

            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("ERROR:::" + response.d);
            }
        });
```

2- The web meothod parameter is string while the address1 is passed as array.

Asp.NET is throwing this error for this. {"Message":"Type \u0027System.String\u0027 is not supported for deserialization of an array...

Create an address container class and set the web method parameter as List:

```
   public class Address
    {
        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string PostCode { get; set; }
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetPostData(List<Address> addresses)
    {
        // addresses[0].Street1;
        // addresses[0].City;
        return null;
    }
```

3- Incase you dont want to change the address javascript array.

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string GetPostData(object address1)
    {
        List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();

        string[][] addresses = new string[2][];

        foreach (var addressList in address1 as object[])
        {
            string[] addressElement = new string[5];
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var temp in addressList as object[])
            {
                addressElement[index++] = (temp != null) ? temp.ToString() : string.Empty;
            }
            list.Add(addressElement);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks , but i want json to be like this only in GetPostData function [["123 Main St", "", "MESA", "AZ", ""], ["5088 n desert ln", "", "PRESCOTT VALLEY", "AZ", "86314"]]

Comment: in 3rd option you can get the array in C#. i.e. in the list object.

Answer (score 0):

If you change your function signature to use an object, you can then convert this object into a C# model using JsonConvert.  Some sample code from an ASP.NET application that I am working on :

```
[Route("api/inviteuser/{model}")]
[HttpPut]
public HttpResponseMessage InviteUser(Object model)
{
    var jsonString = model.ToString();

    InviteUserModel result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<InviteUserModel>(jsonString);

}
```

Where InviteUserModel is a simple C# object:

```
public class InviteUserModel
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public long CurrentCompId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me what is InviteUserModel here ?

Comment: InviteUserModel is the C# model that I am converting the json to.

Comment: See my answer for the two issues.

Comment: Thanks , but i want json to be like this only in GetPostData function [["123  Main St", "", "MESA", "AZ", ""],
        ["5088 n  desert ln", "", "PRESCOTT VALLEY", "AZ", "86314"]]